Tracing files accessed by command?
On Linux I can trivially use strace to trace all file access done by a command that I run from the command line. Is there anything similar for MacOS? I know you can see files that are open by a process using e.g. lsof, but that doesn't work for a process that only runs for a few milliseconds.

This question is not about programming, which makes it off-topic here. General Apple product questions belong on [apple.se]. General computer (hardware, software, OS) questions belong on [su]. We have a site specifically for [ubuntu.se], and a general [unix.se] for other *nix OS questions.  You can find more information about what is acceptable to ask on a site by visiting their [help].
